# How to write these symbols (double times)

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to know how could I do these

[image: double times]

Thank you Steven B. Segletes for your help,
I got the desired result with the code below.

```
\usepackage{stackengine}

\DeclareMathOperator*\dtimes{\times\mkern-11.00mu
  \ensurestackMath{\raisebox{-0.90pt}{\stackanchor[-3.50pt]{\times}{\times}}}
  \mkern-10.90mu\times}
```

[image: topology product]

Comment: Can you show or at least describe, what you already tried?

Comment: I used to use \DeclareMathOperator*{\hash}{\#}, But it feels bad

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\DeclareMathOperator*\dtimes{\times\mkern-7.95mu
  \ensurestackMath{\raisebox{.1pt}{\stackanchor[-.00pt]{\times}{\times}}}
  \mkern-8mu\times
}
\begin{document}
\[
\dtimes_{\lambda \in\Gamma} \mathcal{T}_\lambda
\qquad
\mathcal{T}_\lambda \dtimes \mathcal{T}_\lambda
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

and this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, there are different approaches. Using `\varhash` from `mathabx` package: it is can be rotated if you prefer: the description is adopted in the 2nd MWE with the command `\rotatebox` used with `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\slantedhash}{\scalerel*{\varhash}{\sum}}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\varhash| as sum operator:
\[\underset{\lambda\in\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}}{\slantedhash}\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\]
Using \verb|\varhash| as binary operator:
\[\mathcal{T}_{\lambda} \mathbin{\varhash} \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\]
\end{document}
```

Using `stix` fonts with the rotated command `\equalparallel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\[\underset{\lambda\in\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\equalparallel$}}\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}, \quad \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\equalparallel$} \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `boisik` package there is the symbol: `\smashtimes`. Or using the classic rotation of the symbol `\#`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\[\underset{\lambda\in\Gamma}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$\#$}}\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}, \quad \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$\#$}} \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]